# I want to print the number of the array element in this code

Tags: java, arrays

```
for (j = 0; j < 36; j++)
      {
        System.out.println("Card:" + j + " Index:" + j);
        cardInfo[j].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
          {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
              {
                System.out.println("Index Given:" + j);
                makeCard(j);
              }
          });
      }
```

I have this code and want to print out the number of the array element in

```
System.out.println("Index Given:" +j);
```

`cardInfo[]` is an array of JLabels.

Output always gives:

```
Index Given: 36.
```

Comment: Why don't you use `cardInfo.length`?

Comment: To use variable `j`, it must be `final`. You can create a new variable like: `final int cardIndex = j` and use it instead of `j`.

Comment: Or you can make j final itself.  `for (final j = 0; j < 36; j++)`

Comment: You cannot make j final.  A final variable cannot be changed and so it can never increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time you've called the mouse click handler, j has iterated up to 36. You're facing a problem associated with closure (really interesting topic these days). To get around this try:

```
for(j = 0; j < 36; j++){ 
        System.out.println("Card:" + j + " Index:" + j);
        int indexOfCard = j;
        cardInfo[j].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override 
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){ 
                System.out.println("Index Given:" + indexOfCard);
                makeCard(indexOfCard);
                }
        });
}
```

Comment: Wait, How can indexOfCard can ever be 36 - Loop iterates only from 0 to 35. Isn't ??

Comment: for loop behavior: j hits 35, the loop executes, then j++, the loop goes to check if j < 36, it's not, the for loop terminates, leaving j at 36.

Comment: yes, that's ok. but how does indexOfCard variable initialized to 36 as it does not enter the loop when j = 36.

Comment: Is this technically associated with closure? I'm not certain if I'm entirely correct in my use of that term.

Comment: In answer to your question, the loop increments j at 35, to 36, then checks to see if j < 36, which it isn't, then the loop terminates. The loop will not terminate until j is 36 in this case.